# confusion autoboxing usage with generics

Tags: java, generics, autoboxing

As far as I learn, with Integer example autoboxing usage is:

```
Integer iOb2 = 88; // auto-boxing
Integer iOb = new Integer(88) // is it auto-boxing ? I think no
                              // if it is auto-boxing what about above line?
```

The above code snippet works. However, could you answer the second line whether auto-boxing? With generics, I couldn't get the expected result.

```
// A very simple generic class. 
// Here, T is a type parameter that
// will be replaced by a real type
// when an object of type Gen is created.
class Gen<T> {
  T ob; // declare an object of type T

  // Pass the constructor a reference to 
  // an object of type T.
  Gen(T o) {
    ob = o;
  }

  // Return ob, which is of type T.
  T getob() {
    return ob;
  }
}

// Demonstrate the generic class.
class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Create a Gen reference for Integers. 
    Gen<Integer> iOb; 
    Integer iOb2;
    // Create a Gen<Integer> object and assign its
    // reference to iOb.  Notice the use of autoboxing 
    // to encapsulate the value 88 within an Integer object.
    //iOb = 88; //error
    iOb2 = 88;

    // Get the value in iOb. Notice that
    // no cast is needed.  The type is already known.
    //int v = iOb.getob();
    System.out.println("value: " + iOb2);

    System.out.println();

    // Create a Gen object for Strings.
    Gen<String> strOb = new Gen<String>("Generics Test");

    // Get the value of strOb. Again, notice
    // that no cast is needed.
    String str = strOb.getob();
    System.out.println("value: " + str);
  }
}
```

For this generic code, why isn't the integer value referred to type wrapper type which is `Gen<Integer>`? Whenas, it should be. Shouldn't it?

Comment: "is it auto-boxing ? I think no" You are correct. This is *boxing*, not *auto*-boxing. Auto-boxing is the compile-time substitution of this code (actually, it would be `Integer.valueOf(88)`, I think).

Answer (score 1):

`Integer iOb2 = 88` is implemented by the compiler as `Integer iOb2 = Integer.valueOf(88)`. That is auto-boxing.

`Integer iOb = new Integer(88)` is just you constructing an `Integer` object. Not auto-boxing.

Auto-boxing is only for automatically converting primitive types to their equivalent `Object` versions, e.g. `int` to `Integer`. All auto-boxing operations are done using the `valueOf()` method, which was added in Java 5 for this particular purpose (exception for `Boolean`, where the method already existed).

Therefore, `iOb = 88` is not valid, because `88` is an `int` and that is not assignment compatible with `Gen<Integer>`.

If you wrote `iOb = new Gen<Integer>(88)`, then you would be causing auto-boxing before the object creation, because the constructor needs an `Integer` but you're supplying an `int`.

**PROOF**

To prove that auto-boxing uses `valueOf()`, I created the following code:

```
Boolean   a = true;
Character b = '1';
Byte      c = 1;
Short     d = 1;
Integer   e = 1;
Long      f = 1L;
Float     g = 1f;
Double    h = 1d;
```

Disassembling with the `javap -c` command produced (blank lines added for clarity):

```
 0: iconst_1
 1: invokestatic  #19                 // Method java/lang/Boolean.valueOf:(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
 4: astore_1

 5: bipush        49
 7: invokestatic  #25                 // Method java/lang/Character.valueOf:(C)Ljava/lang/Character;
10: astore_2

11: iconst_1
12: invokestatic  #30                 // Method java/lang/Byte.valueOf:(B)Ljava/lang/Byte;
15: astore_3

16: iconst_1
17: invokestatic  #35                 // Method java/lang/Short.valueOf:(S)Ljava/lang/Short;
20: astore        4

22: iconst_1
23: invokestatic  #40                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
26: astore        5

28: lconst_1
29: invokestatic  #45                 // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
32: astore        6

34: fconst_1
35: invokestatic  #50                 // Method java/lang/Float.valueOf:(F)Ljava/lang/Float;
38: astore        7

40: dconst_1
41: invokestatic  #55                 // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
44: astore        8
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Integer(88)` isn't auto boxing - the closest usable term would be "boxing", but this is really just construction.

In your second code sample, it looks like you're attempting to autobox an `int` into your `Gen` object - that's not how auto boxing works.

Auto boxing only works with the specific types defined in the language - for example `int` can *only* autobox to `Integer`, and not to a type you define (like `Gen`)

Answer (score 0):

`Integer iOb = new Integer(88);` is not auto-boxing, `Integer` takes an `int` parameter in one of its constructor overloads (see [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer(int))).

The `iOb2 = 88` assignment uses auto-boxing, as it's assigning an `int` literal to an `Integer` reference.